# open new browser window (google maps) not as a popup in navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, window.open

I am trying to open google maps in a new browser window in the callback of the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.

The problem is that the browser opens the new window as a popup, because the call is asynchronously. In most browsers the user is asked if he wants to allow the popup. However some browsers (especially mobile browsers) don't show this message. Instead, they just block the popup and for the user it looks like nothing happened.

The first method I tried was (shortened version without error handling etc):

```
$("#getGoogleDirection").on("click",function(e){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(openMap);  
});

function openMap(position){  

    var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var userLng = position.coords.longitude;
    var destinationLat = "<?php echo $destination["lat"]?>";
    var destinationLng = "<?php echo $destination["lng"]?>";

    window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+userLat+","+userLng+"/"+destinationLat+","+destinationLng+"/");

}
```

This works if the browser asks the user if he wants to open the popup. However, as said before some browsers don't ask the user but only block the popup.

So I tried another option:

```
var newWindow;

$("#getGoogleDirection").on("click",function(e){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(openMap);  
    newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    newWindow.document.write('Loading route...');
});

function openMap(position){  

    var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var userLng = position.coords.longitude;
    var destinationLat = "<?php echo $destination["lat"]?>";
    var destinationLng = "<?php echo $destination["lng"]?>";

    newWindow.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"+userLat+","+userLng+"/"+destinationLat+","+destinationLng+"/"';
}
```

This also works. However the problem is that the browser opens the new window, but the confirm popup box for navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is opened in the old window. 
So one must go back to the old window, press the confirm button and then go back to the new window. This is not very convenient for the user.

Is there any possibility to either do the window switching programmatically? Or secondly is it possible to make the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition synchronously, so that I can call

```
window.open()
```

directly in the click event handler of $("#getGoogleDirection") because the it would not be opened as a popup.

Thanks a lot!